# How to get the value of a function outside the loop "while" in C#?

Tags: c#, function, while-loop

```
    bool Estprenom = false;
    while (!Estprenom)
   {
     string prenom = Console.ReadLine();
     if (prenom == "x" || prenom == "y")
     {
        Estprenom = true;
        Console.WriteLine("..." + prenom + "...");
     } 
     else
     {
        Estprenom = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Error " + prenom + " is not your name !\n");
     }              
   }
```

This is my code, and i'd like to know how to use the value " prenom " outside the loop " While ". In this example, the value is set by the user via a " Console.ReadLine ", but I can't use it outside the loop. If I put it before the loop :

```
  bool Estprenom = false;
  string prenom = Console.ReadLine();
```

The loop will never stop if the name written is wrong.

How can I get the value of the string " prenom " outside the loop so I can write :

```
   while (!Estprenom)
    {
    (...)
    }
   Console.WriteLine("..." + prenom );
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Just declare it before the `while` loop and assign it in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply declare the variable outside of the loop and then assign it inside the loop:

```
string prenom;
while (!Estprenom)
{
    ...
    prenom = Console.ReadLine();
    ...
}
Console.WriteLine("..." + prenom );
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pull the prenom value out of the loop scope.

```cs
bool Estprenom = false;
string prenom;
while (!Estprenom)
{
    prenom = Console.ReadLine();
    if (prenom == "x" || prenom == "y")
    {
        Estprenom = true;
        Console.WriteLine("..." + prenom + "...");
    }
    elsestring 
    {
        Estprenom = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Error " + prenom + " is not your name !\n");
    }               
}
Console.WriteLine(prenom);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answers.

Well, I did use your code, but .. It doesn't seem to work. I still got an error.

```
     bool Estprenom = false;
        string prenom;
        while (!Estprenom)
        {
            prenom = Console.ReadLine();
            if (prenom == "x" || prenom == "y")
            {
                Estprenom = true;
                Console.WriteLine("..." + prenom + "...");
            }
            else            
            {
                Estprenom = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Error " + prenom + " is not your name !\n");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(prenom);
```

It's still saying that the "prenom" value in "Console.WriteLine(prenom) is not assigned. I don't understand why...

Comment: I don't see a real problem here. It is a good idea to use the debugger to step trough your code and see exactly what happens. You may want to initialize prenom like this: `string prenom= ''";` This sets prenom to be an empty string.

Comment: I can also recommend a better way to concatenate strings. If you precede the string with a dollar sign, you can use brackets to include variables. This is more efficient and looks a bit better. In your example code: `Console.WriteLine(`$"...{prenom}..."); This works starting with C#6.0 which you should have anyway, the actual version is C#8.0